# Get "arrow" symbol in textField AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, textfield, font-face

I have a textField, which has font face to "Arial", its dynamic. It also takes htmlText.
I am using XML to send data to the textField.

My problem is that I want an arrow "→" in the textField. I have tried embedding "Symbol" font in the swf containing textField but its showing a Register sign.

I'm really stuck with this, any help would be a life-saver!

Comment: have you tried `&rarr;`, `&#8594;`, `&#x2192;`, and `→`?

Comment: I forgot to embed the character. I figured if I embed the "Symbol" font and link it with the textField, it'd work. But turns out these symbols are already in Arial, we just need to manually embed them.
Thanks for the help zzzBov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above, the `&#8594;` and `&#x2192;` both work. Just make sure the characters are embedded.

To be clear, you xml would look a bit like this:

```
<p>This is a &#8594; arrow character</p>
<p>This is another &#x2192; arrow character</p>
```

Comment: I forgot to embed the character. I figured if I embed the "Symbol" font and link it with the textField, it'd work. But turns out these symbols are already in Arial, we just need to manually embed them.
Thanks for the help Misterbenn